# How to extract multiple images contained in HEIC file format?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, heif, heic

I have a HEIC file containing multiple images. How can I extract this image sequence in JPEG or PNG format ?
Is there a NuGet that simplefies the process?

This is for an image handeling software on android, IOS and UWP. I have been looking for a starting point to write this part of the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103811/converting-an-heic-image-to-jpg-and-upload-to-the-server-in-xamarin-ios

Comment: Are you trying to extract those frames using the iOS|macOS framework or if doing this on a server then you can just use something like `ffmpeg` (HEIC is just a container and in an image-burst-based HEIC, there is an embedded hevc/hvc1 video stream (actually there are multiple streams) and you can extract these to "frames"

Comment: Well i am trying to do this offline with-in an Android app / UWP app.

Comment: So i found this Library to help with this Issue.

Comment: So i found this [Library Work-Stuff - HEIF.NET](https://github.com/Work-Stuff/HEIF.NET) that claims to decode and convert HEIF Images and Videos in .NET. I dont know how i can impliment it into my library tho !
on the other hand this [strukturag - libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) comes up often researching the topic ..

Comment: @SushiHangover can you please provide an ffmpeg command for achieving it? I've been trying to see the streams using ffprobe like `ffproble file.heic` but it gives `[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001ab23e4da00] moov atom not found`. And my ffmpeg build was built with `--enable-libx265` support.